# Is VS2012 copy and move operation generation correct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking through the recently released C++ Programming Language 4th Edition checking out the new features. I'm using the VS2012 Update 3 (VC11) compiler, (not ideal I know but it's what I have to use).

17.6 Generating Default Operations states:

```
• If the programmer declares any constructor for a class, the default constructor
is not generated for that class.

• If the programmer declares a copy operation, a move operation, or a destructor
for a class, no copy operation, move operation, or destructor is generated for
that class.
```

My reading of this is that if I declare a copy constructor for a class then the compiler generated copy and move operations and the destructor should all be suppressed.

Yet in VS2012 I see this:

```cpp
struct H{}; // Compiler generated default, copy and move constructors, and
            // destructor. 

struct J
{
    explicit J(int){}
    J(const J&){}   // User copy constructor, so compiler generated default,
                    // copy or move operations and destructor should be
                    // suppressed.
};

void Foo()
{
    H h1;               // Compiler generated default construct.
    H h2 = h1;          // Compiler generated copy construct;
    h1 = h2;            // Compiler generated copy assign.
    H h3 = move(h1);    // Compiler generated move construct.
    h3 = move(h2);      // Compiler generated move assign.

//  J j1;               // Correct. Does not compile. No compiler generated default
                        // constructor.
    J j2(1);            // User constructor.
    J j3 = j2;          // User copy constructor.
    j2 = j3;            // Error? Generated copy assignment should be suppressed.
    J j4 = move(j2);    // Error? Generated move constructor should be suppressed.
    j3 = move(j4);      // Error? Generated move assignment should be suppressed.
}
```

So have I misunderstood, or is the book or the compiler wrong?

Comment: Rvalues *can* bind to const-lvalue references, so your last two lines are fine; assignment operators are defined implicitly, so the third-last line is fine.

Comment: [class.copy]/18(19) "If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted. The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared destructor." (from n3485) So, the third-last line is ok, but deprecated.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like TC++PL(4th) is wrong then.